# Php column table width

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I'm trying to have my columns the same width, when I have empty columns they are the correct size but when I insert tables from a MySQL database, they change and one column is bigger than the others, the one named 'BristolQualification'. I think it might be something to do with the actual table because I've tried moving `BristolQualification` around and it's the same size in each different column. There are two `BathQualification` because I was just playing around and testing. Does anyone know why this could be happening? I've tried replacing them with `width="25%"` (because there are 4 columns 25*4 = 100%).

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("host", "user", "pwd") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("db") or die(mysql_error());

$data = mysql_query("
SELECT  
`Bath`.`BathCountry` ,  
`Bristol`.`BristolCountry` ,  
`Bath`.`BathQualification` ,  
`Bristol`.`BristolQualification` 
FROM  
`Bristol` 
LEFT JOIN  
`Bath` 
ON  
`Bristol`.`BristolCountry` =  `Bath`.`BathCountry` 
ORDER BY  
`Bristol`.`BristolCountry`;
") 
or die(mysql_error());

Echo "<table class=\"imagetable\" border cellpadding=3 style=\"width:100%;\">"; 
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{ 
Echo "<tr>"; 
Echo "<th width=\"100\">Country:</th>
   <th class=\"Bristol\" width=\"100\">Qualifications to Bristol:</th>
   <th class=\"USW\" width=\"100\">Qualifications to USW:</th> 
   <th class=\"Bath\" width=\"100\">Qualifications to Bath:</th>"; 
Echo "</tr>";
Echo "<tr>";
Echo "<td width=\"100\">".$info['BristolCountry'] . "</td> 
   <td class=\"Bristol2\" width=\"100\">".$info['BathQualification'] . " </td> 
   <td class=\"Bath2\" width=\"100\">".$info['BathQualification'] . " </td> 
   <td class=\"USW2\" width=\"100\">".$info['BristolQualification'] . " </td> "  ;
Echo "</tr>"; 
 } 
 Echo "</table>"; 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this CSS properties : `word-break:break-all; word-wrap:break-word`(force your content to fit the block's width)  and `table-layout:fixed` to your table.

```
table {
    word-break:break-all;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
```

Comment: This might sound stupid, but now my text cuts off in the middle of a word at the end instead of going to the next line. For example it 'would stop in the mid
dle of a sentence an
d I don't want that'.

Comment: @Dyl10 :Can you post a fiddle or something?I can't get this error on my machine.

Comment: Never mind, I added word-break: break-word; and it solved it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is occurring because the variables string length are not equal .I had also faced liked that in previous year.You can follow the following instruction to solve this problem .

> Blockquote

```
$info['BathQualification'] 
$info['BathQualification'] 
$info['BristolQualification'] 

Are not all the same size in length. Guess the strings length are l1, l2, l3 respectively. So   
determine that which one is bigger.Suppose that you have determind that l2>l1>l2 .

Then add :
(l2-l1) spaces with $info['BathQualification'] 
(l2-l2) spaces with $info['BathQualification'] 
(l2-l3) spaces with $info['BristolQualification']
```

> Blockquote
>   Now enjoy .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Echo "<table class=\"imagetable\" border cellpadding=3 style=\"width:100%;\">"; 
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{ 
Echo "<tr>"; 
Echo "<th width=\"100\">Country:</th>
<th class=\"Bristol\" width=\"33%\">Qualifications to Bristol:</th>
<th class=\"USW\" width=\"33%\">Qualifications to USW:</th> 
<th class=\"Bath\" width=\"33%\">Qualifications to Bath:</th>"; 
Echo "</tr>";
Echo "<tr>";
Echo "<td width=\"100\">".$info['BristolCountry'] . "</td> 
<td class=\"Bristol2\">".$info['BathQualification'] . " </td> 
<td class=\"Bath2\">".$info['BathQualification'] . " </td> 
<td class=\"USW2\">".$info['BristolQualification'] . " </td> "  ;
Echo "</tr>"; 
} 
Echo "</table>";
```

Also make sure the content doesnt take all the td's space
so if the td has a width of 100px without content, make sure the content of it doesnt take up more than 100px